# Unit tests: manipulate dropdown options to pass form validation

Tags: forms, unit-testing, symfony

I have a form with a mandatory dropdown, but initially is empty. I populate it using jquery (based by an autocomplete field results, I add the option on PRE_SUBMIT event) and is working fine.

The problem is that I can't submit the form in units tests, the list of possible values for my dropdown is empty and I got this error:

> InvalidArgumentException : Input "myform[parent_id]" cannot take "10"
>   as a value (possible values: ).

This is my code in unit tests:

```
$form = $crawler->filter('#myForm')->form();
$params = array(
     'myform[title]'       => 'sample title',
     'myform[parent_id]'   => '10',
     'myform[date]'        => $date->format('Y-m-d')
);
$form->setValues($params);
$client->submit($form);
```

There is any way to manipulate / populate this dropdown to pass the validation?

Thanks!